# Are there any python 3 modules that support OAuth pin-authentication?

Tags: python-3.x, oauth-2.0

What it needs to do:

1. Take a pin generated server-side
2. Get an access token by posting the (pin + client_id + client_secret) to a new URL

The pin can be obtained externally using any browser but if the module supports doing this inline it would be even better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is. One is called sanction and [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26243279/is-it-possible-to-use-pin-authentication-for-sanction-oauth) an example of how to pin-auth.

Go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26148277/python-package-installation-issues) for information on how to install sanction.